# Cannot install Tensorflow 1.13.2 in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio, tensorflow

I'm a newbie to python and Stackoverflow in general so please let me know if something is wrong.

**Problem:** I cannot seem to install Tensorflow 1.13.2 in Visual Code Studio.

The error message is:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.13.2 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.4.0rc0, 2.4.0rc1, 2.4.0rc2, 2.4.0rc3, 2.4.0rc4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.13.2
```

I was able to successfully install this version of Tensorflow with the command prompt on my PC so I'm unsure why VS Code wouldn't be able to find this version.

Is there any ways that I could get this Tensorflow 1.13.2 installed through VS Code?

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: which environment is vs code using? and what's the python version?

Comment: I'm using ver.1.52.1 for VS Code and I'm using python 3.6.12

Comment: I guess you are trying to use `python 3.8` which was not officially supported when tensorflow was at version `1.13`. Actually `python 3.8` support starts from `Tensorflow 2.2` and that is what clearly says in the error.Thanks!